# Random walk over a cube:Probability of returning back

Tags: probability, markov-chains

There is a cube and an ant is performing a random walk on the edges where it can select any of the 3 adjoining vertices with equal probability. What is the probability that ant is in the vertex it started with after N steps?

What I tried->

Breaking problem to simpler one where we see distance from start vertex. So out of 8 vertices, we have 1 with distance 0(our start), 3 with distance 1, 3 with distance 2 and 1 with distance 3.

Also, ant can only return back if N is even. So probability is 0 when N is odd.

Comment: See [OEIS A054879](https://oeis.org/A054879)

Comment: Closely related to a question on Cross Validated: [Random walk on the edges of a cube](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/139384/22228) though that focuses on expected number of moves rather than probabilities, and on reaching the opposite rather than original corner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The probability is zero if $N$ is odd.

After two steps, starting at the original vertex, the probability
of returning there is $1/3$. Otherwise the walk moves to
a vertex at distance $2$ from the original vertex.

Starting at a vertex at distance $2$ from the original vertex,
after two steps the probability it returns to the original vertex
is $2/9$. Otherwise it moves to a vertex at distance $2$ from the original vertex.

So the probability of return after $2n$ steps is the top left
entry of the matrix
$$\pmatrix{1/3&2/3\\2/9&7/9}^n.$$
You can compute this by any standard method (diagonalisation, generating 
functions, etc.).

Comment: This is the same basic idea as Brian's solution, but reducing to a two-state Markov chain instead of a four-state one.

Comment: I like that, that's sort of slick!

Answer (score 13):

**Basic approach.**  I'd take advantage of some symmetries here.  There are three vertices at distance $1$ from the start, three vertices at distance $2$ from the start, and one vertex at distance $3$ from the start.  Show that the distance of the vertex from the start is represented by a four-state Markov chain with the following transition probabilities:

$$
p_{01} = 1
$$
$$
p_{10} = \frac13, p_{12} = \frac23
$$
$$
p_{21} = \frac23, p_{23} = \frac13
$$
$$
p_{32} = 1
$$

Represent this as the matrix $P$.  Then if we denote the initial probability distribution as $\pi = [1 \quad 0 \quad 0\quad 0]^\text{T}$, then $P^N\pi$ represents the probability distribution of the system after $N$ steps, and the probability of being in the start position after $N$ steps can be read off as the first element of the resulting probability vector (i.e., the upper-left element of the matrix).  As you correctly point out, the obvious parity argument shows that the answer must be $0$ for odd $N$.

Matrix exponentiation shows that the result is

$$
\frac14+\frac{1}{4\times3^{N-1}}
$$

Comment: Thanks to Henry for the edit.